# Getting "could not run statement: Incorrect string value:" error when trying to insert Chinese to MySQL via dbExecute()

Tags: mysql, r

I am using **R** (IDE:RStudio) to insert some data back to **MySQL** via **DBI.dbExecute**.
the SQL as follows:
"**INSERT INTO t_tmp(AnalysisDate, Dimension, Indicator, IndicatorType, Value) VALUES('2016-01-17', '维度1', '指标1', '指标类型', 101) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Value = 101;**"

in which "Dimension","Indicator","IndicatorType" are **Chinese**.

when running DBI.dbExecute, I get the error message：
"Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Incorrect string value: '\xB6\xC81' for column 'Dimension'"

**I am trying to paste the SQL to mySQL CLI, and works out just fine(MySQL encoding has set to UTF-8).**

How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try setting the encoding in your R console to UTF-8?

Comment: thanks Tim Biegeleisen , I have checked my RStudio(Tools -> Code -> Saving -> Default text encoding) settings, it has already been UTF-8. Is there any other places I have to check? And I have checked the code '\xB6\xC81' which is exactly the Chinese UTF-8 code.

Comment: I have solved this problem. The problem is still Encoding. My MySQL's encoding is "UTF-8", so after you construct your SQL, transfer it Encoding to "UTF-8"  using iconv(...), then pass it to the dbSendQuery or dbExecute function. then codes are like: statement = "[your sql here with/ without Unicode characters like Chinese]"; statement = iconv(x = statement, to = "UTF-8"); dbSendQuery(conn, statement).                    hope this helps

Comment: thanks thanks Tim Biegeleisen!

Comment: Hi Colin, please post this as an answer below to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. The problem is still Encoding. My MySQL's encoding is "UTF-8", so after you construct your SQL, transfer it Encoding to "UTF-8" using iconv(...), then pass it to the dbSendQuery or dbExecute function. then codes are like: statement = "[your sql here with/ without Unicode characters like Chinese]"; statement = iconv(x = statement, to = "UTF-8"); dbSendQuery(conn, statement). hope this helps